# What is a very simple example of a matrix acting on a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Reading a book about quantum physics, the author described a matrix acting on a vector space. I have not really studied either matrices or vector spaces. But I want to start somewhere, so what is a very simple example of this type of mathematical situation -- a place for me to start?

Comment: Actually the branch of Mathematics which study this kind of situations is Linear Algebra. There are several good books, but a good place to start from is wikipedia:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_algebra

Comment: It doesn't hurt to start with a couple of trivial examples, if only to help pinpoint the understanding you're after: the *identity* matrix leaves every vector unchanged, while the *zero* matrix takes every vector to zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't quite as simple but the matrix $$\left[\matrix{\cos\theta & -\sin\theta \cr \sin\theta&\cos\theta}\right]$$ will rotate each vector in the xy-plane (which forms a vector space, the same space mentioned above, represent each point as an ordered pair (x,y) and define addition and scalar multiplication component-wise)

Try it out! pick a $\theta$ you can compute with easily like $\Large\frac{\pi}{2}$ and see where this matrix sends some points like (1,0) (1,1) [It should rotate them counter-clockwise]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a very elementary example.   Consider the planar vectors with the usual operations of addition and scalar multiplication. This is a vector space.

Now consider the matrix 
$$\left[\matrix{1&0\cr 0&-1}\right]$$
The action on the vector $ai + bj$ by the matrix is defined as follows
$$\left[\matrix{1&0\cr 0&-1}\right]\left[\matrix{a\cr b}\right]$$ to
return $ai - bj$.  Here, this matrix is reflecting the vector $ai + bj$ across
the $x$-axis.

You can see how to reflect across th $y$-axis and the origin.  The multiplication by the matrix defines transformations on the vector it acts upon.

Answer (score 2):

There are two demonstrations on [Wolfram Demonstration Projects](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/index.html) which may offer some intuition：

[Linear Transformations of a Polygon](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/LinearTransformationsOfAPolygon/) and [Linear Transformation Given by Images of Basis Vectors](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/LinearTransformationGivenByImagesOfBasisVectors/)

Answer (score 1):

As other posters have said, the most familiar vector space to start in is the coordinate plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ and space $\mathbb{R}^3$. Your vectors are coordinate points, with vector addition and scalar multiplication being as you think (so $(a,b) + (c,d) = (a+c,b+d)$, and $k(a,b) = (ka,kb)$). Usually you present them vertically, like so: $\begin{bmatrix} a \\ b \end{bmatrix}$.

Matrices map vectors to vectors. Like functions, you can define a domain and range, and some (but not all) matrices have well defined inverses. The notation's usually $Ax=b$, where $A$ is a matrix, and $x$ and $b$ are vectors.

This is a (very basic) starting point, and there good references online, though I haven't used them myself. Here are a few:

- [MIT's Opencourseware on Linear Algebra](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-06-linear-algebra-spring-2010/index.htm)
- [Download for A First Course in Linear Algebra, by David Beezer](http://linear.ups.edu/index.html)
- [Paul's Online Math Notes](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/LinAlg/LinAlg.aspx) for Linear Algebra

Answer (score 1):

A vector space $V$ is a set equipped with addition $+$ operation, and also scalar multiplication by real (complex) numbers and they are distributive with respect to each other (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space) for more detailed definition). The members of this set are rather abstractly called "vectors." A nontrivial example of such spaces that are very much used in physics and engineering is the set of real-valued functions $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ (such as $\sin(t), t^2,...$). Note that one can define sum of two functions by pointwise adding them and define scalar multiplication of a function by a real number, by pointwise multiplying the function with the given scalar.

Now, an $n\times m$ real-valued matrix $A$ acting on a vector space would be exactly similar to matrix acting on real numbers: given any $m$ vectors $v_1,\ldots,v_m$ of $V$ and stacking them on a vector (of vectors) $v=(v_1,\ldots,v_m)^T$, we can define $u=Av$, which is better described by a simple example. For this example, let $V$ to be the vector space of functions $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ and let $v_1=t$ and let $v_2=\sin(t)$. Then:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1&2\\
-1&-1
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
t\\\sin(t)
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}t+2\sin(t)\\ -t-\sin(t)
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

In general, for $v\in V^m$, we can define $u=Av$ as a vector (of vectors) $u\in V^n$, given by:

$$u_i=\sum_{j=1}^mA_{ij}v_j.$$
Note that since $V$ is a vector space (over reals) $A_{ij}v_j$ is defined and hence, $\sum_{j=1}^mA_{ij}v_j$ is also defined and would be in $V$.